# Run-time configuration statements in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Im using SQLAlchemy and Postgres
I need to execute run-time configuration statement `set enable_bitmapscan to off;` before executing any other statements.

Is there any way to create, for example, trigger for new sessions in SQLAlchemy?

If I do it on application startup, it will be executed only on one session, therefore not affecting other sessions.

If I do it on every call of `sessionmaker`, it will be slow, because after some time all sessions will have this statement executed and there is no need to execute it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it by my self:)

You need to add connection arg with this argument

```
engine = create_engine("dsn", connect_args={"options" = "-c enable_bitmapscan=off"})
```